# How does scanf work in char array initializing?

Tags: c

I learned that char array for string like `char s1[10] = "Hello";` has to be initialized with value when it's declared.

But, with `scanf`, it seems like I can declare it without initializing.

I'm wondering how it works.

e.g.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS    
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main() {
    char s1[6];
    s1 = "Hello" // It does not work.
    scanf("%s", s1); // And write Hello, it works. Why does it work?

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for reading

Comment: Your learning is wrong. Use `strcpy()` to copy strings.

Comment: You can't assign to arrays, only copy to them.

Comment: As for `scanf` and how it "initializes" the array, it copies one character at a time into the array, beginning by the pointer to the first element (which you pass with the argument).

Comment: It should be noted that using `scanf` on strings is dangerous as it doesn't protect against overrunning memory.